# How to use @Autowired in unit tests?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, autowired

Is it the better approach to autowire a bean as a private instance field or when the test is invoked?

```
@SpringBootTest
class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository myRepository;

    @Test
    void shouldDoSomething(@Autowired MyRepository myRepository) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to autowire the bean as a field:

1. if it is used by multiple tests.
2. if I need to modify the bean in @BeforeEach - here you clearly see that this would be repeated for each test so it corresponds to point 1. But this is dangerous and should be used with caution, because the bean is "global" - it is shared among the tests.
3. if there is only one test in the whole test class

and autowire the bean as a method parameter if it can be considered as a "local variable" in the method and is not used by other tests.